# Use parameter throughout my method or declare variable?

Tags: c#, variables

Let's say I have a method like this:

```
private void Method(string parameter)
{
    // do some stuff with parameter
}
```

Is it acceptable to just use the parameter inside the method or is it better to declare a local variable as such:

```
private void Method(string parameter)
{
    string localvariable = parameter;
    // do some stuff with local variable
}
```

Does it matter performancewise? Is it more stable to declare a local variable?

Comment: Performance will be worse in the second case, because it has to copy the string contents into another variable. The compiler might be smart enough to notice that the parameter is never used after that, and alias `localvariable` to it, but I wouldn't depend on this optimization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, there is no reason to assign a parameter's value to a local variable. In fact, a parameter is simply a special type of local variable that receives the value of the arguments passed to the method, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter_(computer_programming). You should use it throughout your method.  Unless explicitly passed by reference, parameters are passed by value so you will not affect the value passed into the method call.  When passing reference types, the "value" being passed is the reference (pointer) to the object so modifying properties or performing operations on the object that modify it will result in changes to it.  For value types and strings which, being immutable, are treated specially, you should not have to worry about side effects to the variables passed to the method.